Is there a way to remove text formatting/custom fonts in my UWP app?
I'm creating a simple chat application and I wonder if there is a simple way of "sanitizing" user chats to prevent the use of crazy fonts...
Ñ̵̩͕͝ä̸̧̧̬̯́̀̊̅͌̋̃̕͝m̷̛̛̦͍̠͕͍̈̇͂̽̆͛̿͆ę̸̡̡̙͎́̎̑̕l̴̛̝͚̪̂̓̓̅̈́̃͑y̴͍̑̔͑̚ͅ,̵͇̠͎̻͇͗̈̾̍̈͑̏̿͝ ̷̡̨̱͍̣̣̱̜̈͑̀s̸̗͖̻̦̭͙̙͇̼̜͋͑̀̿̇̽̊t̴̞̟̭̞͇͙͙̝̻͆͋̅͂ű̷̢̮̥̦̥̼̮̙̹͘͝p̸̡̧̻͓͛̒͒́̚͠͠i̵͈͖͕̯̜̮̰͚̥̩͋̊͋̈́d̶̛͚̹̜̙̹̏̎̑̚͝ ̶̛̙͔̦͚̠̦̹̋͆̚͝f̸͚̭̙͓͇̪̅͊͊͌̇͜o̷̫̝̳̼͑͊̋̊̏̚͜͝ṋ̵̆͐̀͛̈́̇̀̑̚͘ţ̶̧͖̮͙̗̗̱͙͛̇̚ ̶̨̡̧́́͒̏͜t̴̮͂͊̍̈͂́͠ͅȑ̶̝̥͖̫͔̯̥̭̹̔̆ͅì̵͕̟̏̓̀̄̆̈́̕̚c̸̡̨̺̯̼̀̀k̷̻͕̒̍̅̂̄̄̍͆s̸̨̤̥͙͇̯͇̬̒̄͝ ̵̛̫̹͈̠̞̩̗̲̘̇̆͝l̶̨̰̈́̃̂ḯ̴̝̣̤ͅk̵͚͙̖͙̩̤̿̋͛̿̎̽͊̒̈̕e̸͖̣̘̟͐̈́̀͑̄̊͒̒͝ ̶̡̬̜͒͂̓͗̓̓̚t̴̛̛͕̗͔͍͋͊̍͆̚͝h̵̡̧̧̨̧̗͍͍͕̦̀͐̇̉̓̈́̚ì̶̢̳̠̤̖̝̝͙̦̟̈́̍̇͘͝s̴̯͝
Is there a good way of going about this?

Enforce ASCII encoding? Is there a specific reason to not allow it?

This thing is done by using combining characters. I guess you can create a list of such characters and simply filter them.

If someone curious, the OP example is called zalgo text, there are online tools to generate one, e.g. here.

@Fildor to prevent vulgar language and crazy text like that text above. Thanks, that answered my question!

Ok. I don't really see the connection and I am pretty confident you can be extremely vulgar in ACII, too. But you do you.

Quite few other languages are supported in ASCII, så if you plan to go global with your code, a lot will end up disappointed. E.g. In Danish we have æøå, in sweedish they have ö, in germany they have ẞ in the native alphabets.

^^ this. I also think that for effective counter-profanity, you probably won't be able to avoid (human) moderation.
